# How to migrate AAS/SSAS cube to Power BI premium?

Tags: powerbi

We have few cubes located in on-prem SSAS and on AAS (Azure analysis services). The report connect to the cube via live connection.

We are planning to migrate the cubes into the Power BI Premium workspace.

I want to ask - how do I migrate the cube from analysis services to Power BI Premium? Do I publish the model from visual studio analysis services project into Power BI premium workspace? Or do I convert the visual studio analysis services project into .pbix based data model?

Answer (score 6):

Hi Easiest way is to migrate using [Tabular Editor](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/tabular-editor/)

First in power bi make sure you have enabled XMLA endpoint read write enabled in the tenant. Refer below SS
[image: PBI tenant settings]

Get the analysis services url and click on From DB and paste the AAS url

[image: Tabular from DB]

[image: AAS URL]

Be mindful of the [compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/compatibility-level-for-tabular-models-in-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions) Recommending to put it into 1565 range

[image: C level]

After this deploy into the premium workspace.

[image: deploy]

Get the wokrspace connection string from below mentioned place.

[image: WP url]

Paste it in below.

[image: Paste]

Deploy by picking following settings.

[image]

And Deploy.

[image]

****UPDATE****

Now AAS model migration is available natively in powerbi refer below link for more information,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/aas-pbi-migration-overview

Comment: Same process for SSAS?

Comment: Yes. Similar process for SSAS

Comment: Great write-up, saving for later reference!

Answer (score 4):

Deploying the code like @amelia suggested is a great way to migrate and the answer was extremely well written. For AAS there is a new [built-in migration process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/aas-pbi-migration-overview) which backs up and restores the AAS model to Power BI. Then it enables redirection so that existing Excel reports (or other client tools) automatically are redirected to Power BI.